# VMware ESXi, Format first or?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am looking to install the free VMware ESXi on an existing server that currently has Windows Server 2003 installed. We currently have a box running VMware server but this will be my first run in with ESXi. The RAID configuration is already setup as I want but I'm wondering if I should first format the drives using something like gParted or will the ESXi installer format the drives prior to install? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESXi installer will recommend sizes for the various partitions it needs.  You can accept its recommendations or customize them, and then it will partition the disk for you.